# Deploy Django project using wsgi and virtualenv on shared webhosting server without root access

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, wsgi

I have a Django project which I would like to run on my shared webspace (1und1 Webspace) running on linux. I don't have root access and therefore can not edit apache's httpd.conf or install software system wide.

What I did so far:

- installed squlite locally since it is not available on the server
- installed Python 3.5.1 in ~/.localpython
- installed virtualenv for my local python
- created a virtual environment in ~/ve_tc_lb
- installed Django and Pillow in my virtual environment
- cloned my django project from git server

After these steps, I'm able to run `python manage.py runserver` in my project directory and it seems to be running (I can access the login screen using lynx on my local machine).

I read many postings on how to configure fastCGI environments, but since I'm using Django 1.9.1, I'm depening on wsgi. I saw a lot about configuring django for wsgi and virtualenv, but all examples required access to httpd.conf.

The shared web server is apache.
I can create a new directory in my home with a sample hello.py and it is working when I enter the url, but it is (of course) using the python provided by the server and not my local installation.
When I change the first line indicating which python version to use to my virtual environment (`#!/path/to/home/ve_tc_lb/bin/python`), it seems to use the correct version in the virtual environment. Since I'm using different systems for developing and deployment, I'm not sure whether it is a good idea to e.g. add such a line in my `djangoproject/wsgi.py`.

Update 2016-06-02
A few more things I tried:

- I learned that I don't have access to the apache error logs
- read a lot about mod_wsgi and django in various sources which I just want to share here in case someone needs them in the future:

  - [modwsgi - IntegrationWithDjango.wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/IntegrationWithDjango.wiki%20modwsgi%20-%20IntegrationWithDjango.wiki)
  - [debug mod_wsgi installation](https://serverfault.com/questions/153859/how-to-check-if-mod-wsgl-has-correcly-installed-in-apache) (only applicable if you are root)
  - [mod_wsgi configuration guide](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html)
- I followed [the wsgi test script installation here](http://rudepeklo.blogspot.de/2010/02/running-django-on-shared-hosting-with.html) - but the wsgi-file is just displayed in my browser instead of beeing executed.

All in all it seems like my provider 1und1 did not install wsgi extensions (even though the support told me a week ago it would be installed)

Update 2016-06-12: I got a reply from support (after a week or so :-S ) confirming that they dont have mod_wsgi but wsgiref...

So I'm a bit stuck here - which steps should I do next? 
I'll update the question regularly based on comments and remarks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My personal experience with any generic AMP shared host ISP is always painful. There are some budget ISP that target Django, there are PaaS providers like Heroku and cheap VPS like DigitalOcean. Sadly, WSGI applications are not like deploying PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your apache is shared, I don't expect you can change the httpd.conf but use instead your solution. My suggestion is:

1. If you have multiple servers you will deploy your project (e.g. testing, staging, production), then do the following steps for each deploy target.
2. In each server, create a true `wsgi.py` file **which you will never put in versioning systems**. Pretty much like you would do with a `local_settings.py` file. This file will be named `wsgy.py` since most likely you cannot edit the apache settings (since it is shared) and that name will be expected for your wsgi file.
3. The content for the file will be:

   ```
    #!/path/to/your/virtualenv/python
    from my_true_wsgi import *
   ```

   Which will be different for each deploy server, but the difference will be, most likely, in the shebang line to locate the proper python interpreter.
4. You will have a file named `my_true_wsgi` to have it matching the import in the former code. That file will be in the versioning systems, unlike the `wsgi.py` file. The contents of such file is the usual contents of the `wsgi.py` on any regular django project, just that you are not using that name directly.

With this solution you can have several different wsgi files with no conflict on shebangs.

Comment: This is definitely helpful in generla, but unfortunately I'm stuck one step prior to that. If I don't find an other solution, You will recieve the rep points since your answer might help others having a similar problem.

Comment: What do you mean with *one step prior*? Where are you stuck?

Comment: in fact I don't succeed in running *any* wsgi application right now. At the moment it seems like they have no mod_wsgi installed, even though support told me they do :-S

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a webhost that supports Django. See https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoFriendlyWebHosts. Personally, I've used [WebFaction](https://www.webfaction.com/) and was quite happy with it, their support was great and customer service very responsive.

Comment: not really - you need a webhost that supports wsgi - and that seems to be the problem in my case.

Comment: Fair enough, but many of those hosts, including WebFaction (at least at the time I used it), do use wsgi. Additionally, if they have good support they may be willing to apply configurations for you that require root.